# `*.html` servlet has priority over `document.html` controller mapping in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I have a servlet annotated with `@WebServlet("*.html")` and a controller with `@GetMapping("/greeting.html")`. Despite the controller mapping being more specific, the servlet takes precedence.

In my application I can't trivially change the mapping of the servlet (I'm in the middle of a complex migration from  servlets to Spring-Boot).

I tried `@Order` annotation, and different matching rules. So far no progress.

You can reproduce it with just 3 classes:

`application.java`

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

`GreetingController.java`

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting.html")
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {
        return "this is geeting.html";
    }

}
```

`SimpleServlet.java`

```java
package hello;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@WebServlet("/*.html")
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("This is *.html servlet");
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

When accessing `localhost:8080` I expect to see `this is geeting.html`, instead I get `This is *.html servlet`.